# Esperar un forEach antes de seguir

Tags: javascript, mysql, callback

Llevo un par de dias trabajando en este código.

Tengo dos consultas a mysql que se repiten con un `forEach`, y necesito esperar a que ambos `forEach` se completen si o si antes de seguir.

Explico mi codigo:

Una funcion que debe devolver un `array` con objetos, esta función recibe el **`id_user`** a buscar un 'cb'  - que es una función callback que se encargara de manejar el array y mostrarlo en pantalla - .

En principio hago un **`select`** que me trae un `array` de ids que me servirán para la segunda consulta. Luego esta segunda consulta se repite en un bucle para traer un `array` de objetos de distintas tablas, los cuales 'desglozaré' en el segundo `for` para ir acumulándolos en mi `array` llamado 'matches'.

Mi objetivo es que el array 'matches' se llene de objetos que provienen de distintas tablas pero que tienen en común un **`id_user`**.

---

El problema es que la función `forEach` es asíncronica - lo que hace que se ejecute la linea `cb(e,matches)` antes de terminar los `for`, consiguiendo por pantalla un `array` vació.

Estube leyendo sobre Promesas, pero no hay caso, no logro entenderlas, los ejemplos de internet son muy básicos y no logro encajar este concepto en mi código.

¿Alguien conoce cómo puedo solucionar esta situación?

Este es mi código:

```
var getMatchByUser=(id_user,cb)=>{
    let matches=[];

    db.query(`SELECT id_community FROM members_community WHERE id_user=${id_user}`,[],(e,d)=>{
       d.forEach(m=>{
          db.query(`SELECT * FROM matches_${m.id} WHERE created_by=${id_user}`,[],(e1,d1)=>{
            d1.forEach(m1 => {
                matches.push(m1);
            });
          });
       });
       cb(e,matches);
    });
}
```

Comment: Saludos. ¿Hay posibilidad de que ambas consultas estén unificadas - *(es decir, que no tenga la necesidad de usar dos select separados)*?. La verdad no me es claro por qué estás haciendo dos consultas... Puedes mirar esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1544/78) acerca de cómo obtener los resultados de una llamada asíncrona.

Comment: Qué devuelve `db.query()`? Dónde puedo ver la documentación de ese método?

Comment: Hola buenas, puedes usar `Promise()`. Lo que hace es esperar que se ejecuten funciones necesarias y despues hacer lo que quieres. Resumido, te obliga a esperar que las funciones asincronas se completen una a una y solo DESPUES hacer lo que tu quieres. Aqui tienes la documentación https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=es

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave, no, no tengo manera, ya que las tablas con nombre `matches_{numero}` pueden ser cientos o miles, mientras que el array de la primera consulta tiene un máximo de 20 registros, de esta manera hago una especie de "filtro". Necesito que la segunda query se repita N cantidad de veces dependiendo la cantidad de registros obtenidos en la primera query.
Y ya una vez terminado todo ejecutar la `cb(e,matches)` enviando el array `matches` con los objetos obtenidos de todos lados

Comment: @Crystal si echas un vistazo a mi respuesta, ahí tienes la solución.

Answer (score 1):

El método `db.query()` es el asíncrono pero no sé si devuelve una promesa o no. Actualmente lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

```
// query 1. este es un método asíncrono
db.query(`SELECT id_community FROM members_community WHERE id_user=${id_user}`,[],(e,d)=>{

    // en su callback, recorremos uno de los objetos de respuesta
    d.forEach(m => {

        // query 2. estas llamadas son asíncronas, por lo que se lanzan pero continúa la ejecución
        db.query(`SELECT * FROM matches_${m.id} WHERE created_by=${id_user}`,[],(e1,d1)=>{
            d1.forEach(m1 => {
                matches.push(m1);
            });
        });
    });

    // esto se lanza antes de finalizar query 2
    cb(e,matches);
});
```

Lo que podemos hacer en este caso para tener un control sobre los métodos asíncronos, es crear nuestras propias promesas:

```
// convertimos el método en async para poder utilizar awaits
const getMatchByUser = async(id_user, cb) => {
    const matches = [];

    // creamos un método usable para obtener las consultas de la bd (este método podría/debería estar fuera de este scope)
    const doQuery = query => new Promise(resolve => db.query(query, [], (e, d) => resolve([e, d]));

    // recogemos la primera consulta
    const [a, b] = await doQuery(`SELECT id_community FROM members_community WHERE id_user=${id_user}`);

    // recorremos los resultados
    b.forEach(m => {

        // recogemos la segunda consulta
        const [c, d] = await doQuery(`SELECT * FROM matches_${m.id} WHERE created_by=${id_user}`);

        // recorremos los resultados
        d.forEach(ml => matches.push(ml));
    });

    // utilizamos los resultados
    cb(a, matches);
};
```

Comment: si, gracias, es masomenos lo que estoy tratando de conseguir. si bien este código no funciona me da una idea de por donde encarar.
En este codigo nunca entra el bucle `b.forEach`, salta de una al `cb` con el mismo resultado

Comment: Está hecho al vuelo, sin probar, pero a excepción de algún typo que pueda haber debería funcionar. Cualquier cosa por aquí andamos

Comment: Hmm le has puesto la declaración `async` a `getMatchByUser()`? Puedo equivocarme pero a priori un copy&paste debería funcionar.

Comment: eso es indistinto ya que tiene su propio callback para manejar lo que suceda. en tu código me exige por sintaxis que la linea `const[c,d]=await doQuery...` este dentro de una función async, lo que desacredita y deja inutilizable el `forEach`. este forEach es el que es asincronico, no se detiene a completar el bucle, sigue a la siguiente linea del `cb`

Comment: El `forEach` es asíncrono? Lo leí en tu pregunta pero di por hecho que era un error y que era `db.query()` el asíncrono, de ahí que tuviera un callback. Le doy una vuelta al código y edito la respuesta cuando lo tenga, a ver si lo sacamos adelante.

Comment: Ese `forEach` pertenece a nodejs?

Comment: si bien estoy utilizando nodejs, `forEach` es nativo de cualquier array de el mismo javascript .___.

Comment: Sí, pero no es asíncrono. En cambio, si no me equivoco, en nodejs se puede utilizar una librería `async` la cual tiene un método `forEach()`. La pregunta ahora, antes de hacer nada, es: el `forEach()` que estás utilizando es el nativo de js (síncrono) o es asíncrono? Qué tipo de objeto devuelve `db.query()` en su callback?

Comment: el clásico `Array.prototype.forEach()` que debería ser sincrono. Igual estoy intentando convertir cada bucle en promesa y obligarlas a esperar, no es lo mejor pero debería funcionar

Comment: Entonces el `forEach()` no es asíncrono en absoluto! No sé si llegaste a hacerlo, pero, si copias el código que puse en la respuesta al completo (con su declaración async en la función), no funciona? Porque veamos, si lo que devuelve `db.query()` es un simple array, ese snippet debería funcionar tal cual está. Antes comentaste que al utilizar la declaración `async` dejaba inutilizable los `forEach()` pero por qué motivo?