# Por que array.push(""); no me funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un problema, yo primero creo una array llamado "errores", si en mis solicitudes ajax se encuentran problemas entonces voy hacer un push en el array, pero nada ya depure el codigo y no llena el array osea no hace push, pero si agrego un alert en su lugar pues hay si lo llama, quiere decir que si entra en .fail, pero no se por que no funciona el push, alguien que me ayude por fa

```js
const inicioClass = (function() {

  var errores = [];

  var obtenerSliders = function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "models/slider/obtenerSliders.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
      if (response.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          // prettier-ignore
          var template = "Slider"

          $("#div-sliders").append(template);
        }
      }
    });

    request.fail(function() {
    //aqui no hace el push, pero si entra en fail
      errores.push("Slider");
    });
  };

 
  var verificarPagina = function() {
    if(errores.length > 0){
      //mostrarMensajeAlerta();
    }
  };

  // Public Functions
  return {
    // public functions
    init: function() {
      obtenerSliders();
      verificarPagina();
    }
  };
})();


// Class Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
  inicioClass.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: prueba inspeccionar la variable en el inspector y verifica si al darte un error esta se esta llenando

Comment: Define `var errores = [];` dentro de esta `var obtenerSliders = function() {` y me cuentas , ya que probé tu `array` y le hice push y funciono.

Comment: Amigo, hola, ya hice de todo, inspeccione y si entra al .fail pero no hace push en el array, probe remplazando el array, poniendo un simple alert y si lo manda no se que pasa, no se si error de mi logica

Comment: Francisco voy a probar.

Comment: Esto esta dado a la naturaleza de las llamadas `Ajax` algo que me he dado cuenta y que no esta escrito es que con las funciones anonimas no podras extraer nada de la llamada, ahora bien, usa las funciones de flecha `request.fail( ()=> {
    //aqui no hace el push, pero si entra en fail
      errores.push("Slider");
    });`

Comment: Francisco, voy puedo declarar el array dentro esa funcion ya que el array lo tengo que usar a nivel global por que lo uso en otras funciones

Comment: Pero has la prueba, solo para ese metodo para saber si se esta perdiendo el contexto del array, revisa que error te aparece undefined o solo no entra no arroja nada ?

Comment: Alber Hidalgo, la funcion verificarPagina, si realiza lo que yo le digo, el mira el largo de errores y me va a mostrar un mensaje de alerta o no, eso si lo hace el problemaesta en las otras funciones que cuando entra a .fail no hace3push en el array

Comment: francisco si lo hace, y si hago push fuera de una funcion tambien lo hace, no se que pasa, pero necesito tener el array a nivel global y hacerle push solo cuando una solicitud ajax me de error

Comment: cambia el `var` ponle `let` y prueba a ver si te deja hacerle push, si te deja te explico el por que.

Comment: Nada, esto es demasiado raro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa este `snippet`, no hice nada, solo agrega `consoles` para validar como se comportaba tu código y funciona , solo tiene agregada la referencia `Jquery`, Si revisas el metodo  `verificarPagina`  se esta ejecutando primero que el que inserta los errores en el array

```js
const inicioClass = (function() {
console.log('incial el metodo inicioClass');

  var errores = [];
console.log('array errores' + errores);
  var obtenerSliders = function() {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "models/slider/obtenerSliders.php",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json"
    });

    request.done(function(response) {
      if (response.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          // prettier-ignore
          var template = "Slider"

          $("#div-sliders").append(template);
        }
      }
    });

    request.fail(function() {
    //aqui no hace el push, pero si entra en fail
      errores.push("Slider 1");
      errores.push("Slider 2");
      console.log('Array push - ' + errores)
    });
  };

 
  var verificarPagina = function() {
   
      //mostrarMensajeAlerta();
       console.log('Array verifica - ' + errores)
    
  };

  // Public Functions
  return {
    // public functions
    init: function() {
      obtenerSliders();
      verificarPagina();
    }
  };
})();


// Class Initialization
$(document).ready(function() {
  inicioClass.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Si me di cuenta de que esa funcion se ejecuta primero, me di cuenta al poner console, pero por que pasa esto? si en el init las declaro en orden

Comment: Déjame pruebo algo y edito la respuesta

Comment: Las funciones se ejecutan de manera extraña, no tienen el orden que yo les asigno :'(

Comment: Obvio no ya que en javascript se ejecutan de modo asincronico, hay que asegurarse que primero se ejecute una y después la otra ya estoy revisando

Comment: Ok gracias amigo.

Comment: 1. incial el metodo inicioClass

2.  Console, aqui se declara el array vacio - inicio.js:5

3.  Console, esta es la funcion que verifica si el array tiene elementos, deberia tener 2: - inicio.js:143

4.  Console, aqui se hacen dos push al array, deberian haber dos elementos : Slider 1,Slider 2 -  inicio.js:64

La funcion verificar se ejecuta antes

Comment: Amigo no pudiste solucionarlo? parece que toca usar promesas

Comment: Si, toca usar promesas, no corregi la respuesta ya que la pregunta tiene duplicado, Mira esta (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1539/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-la-respuesta-de-una-llamada-as%c3%adncrona-ajax-fuera-de-ella )

Comment: Si ya me di cuenta y lo vi, pero me ha costado implementarlo a mi codigo, no me va muy bien esto del javascript moderno tengo que practicar mas, me echas una mano?

Comment: Ya eh podido familiarizarme con las promesas, voy a dar tu respuesta como correcta!